# How can I import data from an XLS file to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

As I am trying to import MS Excel data to MySQL data base 
using the following code:

```
<?php  
    $db_username="root"; //database user name
    $db_password="";//database password
    $db_database="hr_mysql"; //database name
    $db_host="localhost";


    mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password);
    @mysql_select_db($db_database) or die( "Unable to connect to database.");

    $handle = fopen("UploadIt.xls", "r"); //test.xls excel file name
    if ($handle)
    {
        $array = explode("\n", fread($handle, filesize("UploadIt.xls")));
    }

    $total_array = count($array);
    $i = 0;
    $Leave_Type_Id1="LTY001";
    $Leave_Type_Id2="LTY002";

    while($i < $total_array)
    {
    $data = explode(",", $array[$i]);    
    //$sql = "insert into test values ('$data[0]','$data[1]')";
    $sql = "update `hs_hr_employee_leave_quota` set `no_of_days_allotted`= {$data[0]} WHERE `employee_id`= {$data[0]} and `leave_type_id`= '{$Leave_Type_Id1}'";        
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $sql = "update `hs_hr_employee_leave_quota` set `no_of_days_allotted`= {$data[2]} WHERE `employee_id`= {$data[0]} and `leave_type_id`= '{$Leave_Type_Id2}'";        
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $i++;
    }
    if($result==false)
            echo "Not succed";  
    else 
    {
        echo "completed";   
    }

?>
```

And my .xls sheet is:

But I am getting error saying

htdocs\Verify\XL_To_DBTable.php line 28 - Undefined offset:  2

### |1|2|5|

### |2|3|5|

### |3|3|4|

### |4|3|9|

### |5|4|1|

(Assume above one as xls sheet only)

Comment: What is the xl file you are referring too?  Is it a text file or MS Excel?

Comment: You could try this direct Excel Data Import - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly read the file as an MS Excel file.  You are treating it as an ascii text file.  You could manually dump the file to CSV format and parse it using similar logic to what you have already.  Or you could use:

[PHP Excel File Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)

and use that to parse the file, get the contents and then create the appropriate queries to be executed in mysql.

Comment: I renamed the .xls file into .csv file. Is that Ok..? And After that also I am getting the error. As XL_To_DBTable.php line 29 - Undefined offset:  2.

Comment: Hi @Wes, I have noticed that it is fetching and referring the data from Sheet3.

Comment: @Gnanendra You can't just rename the file you have to like I said in the answer manually open the file in Excel and the export it csv format if you are going that route.

Comment: @Gnanendra Unless you meant you had a csv file to start with and renamed the file and it is now getting the contents correctly.

Comment: I have tried to export csv but I didn't  get the option to do so. If you don't mind please could you tell me that how to export it to csv?

Comment: Thanku very much @Wes... Its woring fine. with out changing my code. All b'coz of ur suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: @gnanendra Cool.  Now be kind and accept my solution as the answer :)